# Spring Boot JPA Herencia

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Espero puedan ayudarme en decirme si es posible lo que quiero realizar, tengo la clase padre `Respuesta`, y la clases hija `RespuestaTipoUno` y `RespuestaTipoDos` todas son clases entity mapeadas a su respectiva tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La clase padre la tengo con la etiqueta de herencia

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

tengo otra clase llamada `Preguntas` la cual contiene un listado de la clase padre `Respuesta`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"pregunta"}, allowSetters = true)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pregunta", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> respuestas;
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, se construyen adecuadamente las tablas y relaciones, el temas es que cuando hago una petición post para crear datos en la tabla preguntas al tener como atributo la clase Padre Respuestas me ignora por completo si le mando atributos de la clases hija y no me inserta en estos, solo me inserta los datos en la tabla padre, mi pregunta es si hay una forma de que la clase Entity pueda identificar que clase hija se esta mandando desde el postman, si es la clase RespuestaTipoUno, la clase RespuestaTipoDos, o incluso si solo es instancia de la clase Respuesta, espero haberme dado a entender.

He intentado en el set de la clase Preguntas hacer la asignacion de la respectiva clase hija pero no me sirvió lo siguiente:

```html
public void setRespuestas(List<Answer> respuestas) {
        this.respuestas.clear();
        respuestas.forEach(r->{
            if(r instanceof CategoryAnswer) {
                CategoryAnswer c = (CategoryAnswer) r;
                addRespuesta(c);
            }
            else {
                addRespuesta(r);
            }
        });
    }
```

Agrego el metodo post de mi controller, es un controller comun:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> crear(@RequestBody E entity){
    E entityDb = service.save(entity);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(entityDb);
}
```

Comment: Lo primero es identificar el problema. ¿Es JPA el que te ignora las subclases? ¿O es que al recibir los datos el WS solo te crea instancias de `Answer`? El segundo trozo de código no te ayuda, Java no es como C++ y el hacer cast de la variable realmente no hace nada (en Java es como si todas las referencias a objetos fueran punteros de C++).

Comment: Estaría bien ver el código del controlador, creo que el problema es cómo está planteada la lógica

Comment: Te explicas un poco mal. Cuales son tus entidades y cuales DTO tienes. La clase pregunta no deberia ser hija de respuesta o eso das a entender tu. Pon los metodos del controlador y ponme las tablas y los dto y busco comoa yudarte

Comment: @SJuan76 al parecer solo me crea instancias de Answer, puse un breakpoint en el service para ver el objeto y solo se crea la instancia de Answer, es decir que los demas datos se pierden.

Comment: @PabloLozano ya agregue mi método post del controller, es un controller común, el controller de pregunta extiende de este controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás esperando que Spring haga más trabajo del que puede hacer:

Si tienes un controlador con genéricos para poder crear controladores específicos, algo así como

```
class AnswerController extends CrudController<Answer> {...}
```

Java en tiempo de compilación declará el parámetro como de la clase Answer y Spring simplemente verá esa clase. No tiene porqué saber que esa clase tiene hijas, ni qué diferencia una clase de otra.

Por tanto **siempre** usará la clase Answer para hacer el mapping.

Si queremos ser puristas, se considera una mala idea usar clases *entidad* (modelo de persistencia) en la capa de controladores, de hecho deberias desacoplar tu API de tu modelo usando una clase DTO:

```
class AnswerController extends CrudController<AnswerDTO> {...}
```

Por ejemplo, este DTO podría tener todos los atributos de Answer y de sus hijas, agrupando todas las posibles opciones. Luego, en tu controlador,podrías ver qué campos han sido rellenados y crear una instancia de la entidad que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenia la duda de si se podía realizar o no esa acción, pensé en lo que mencionas más quise ver antes si era posible, muchas gracias lo haré de esa forma. Saludos.